# PySpark Code for Data Masking Modification

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Can someone help modify the following PySpark code to mask certain characters in a field.
As it stands the code will mask all the characters in a field, for example it will turn the following email address from customername@hotmail.com to 7cdc15144825a91b55330425e3d109df77a31baf9b7e9a4597a047bf20470178.

However, I would like to only mask say the first five characters with ***** so it appears as ******mername@hotmail.com

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf  
import hashlib  
  
class Mask:  
    def __init__(self, salt: str):  
        self.salt = salt  
      
    def sha512(self, value):  
        return hashlib.sha512(f'{value}{self.salt}'.encode()).hexdigest()  
  
    def shake_128(self, value):  
        return hashlib.shake_128(f'{value}{self.salt}'.encode()).hexdigest(32)  
  
    def register(self, spark: SparkSession):  
        spark.udf.register('sha512', self.sha512)  
        spark.udf.register('shake128', self.shake_128)


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()  
m= Mask('123456789')  
m.register(spark) 


To use the code to mask email address would be as follows

spark.read \  
    .format('csv') \  
    .option('inferSchema', True) \  
    .option('header', True) \  
    .load(path) \  
    .selectExpr(['user_name', 'shake128(email)']) \  
    .write \  
    .mode('append') \  
    .saveAsTable('my_table')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions`'s [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) function for that:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("some-email-address@hotmail.com",),
        ("superniceaddress@hotmail.com",),
        ("short@hotmail.com",),
        ("whatsup123@hotmail.com",),
    ],
    ["email"],
)

df.select(
    F.regexp_replace("email", r"(^[^@]{1,5})", "*****").alias("masked_emails")
).show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------+
|masked_emails                 |
+------------------------------+
|*****email-address@hotmail.com|
|*****niceaddress@hotmail.com  |
|*****@hotmail.com             |
|*****up123@hotmail.com        |
+------------------------------+
```

**NOTE**: if the part before the `@` sign is less than 5 characters long you'll still get 5 `*` signs. I imagine that is no problem since you're trying to mask data.